# Multiple filters / Filter inside filter - React Native

Tags: react-native, filter

how can i do something like that in React-Native:

```js
data = [
           {id:1,title:'Action',games:[
               {id:1,title:'Game1'},
               {id:2,title:'Game2'},
               {id:3,title:'Game3'},
           ]},
           {id:2,title:'Horror',games:[
               {id:1,title:'Game1'},
               {id:2,title:'Game2'},
               {id:3,title:'Game3'},
           ]},

       ]
```

Every time the query string is updated, look for the game within the category.

Returns only the categories that contain a game with the searched characters.

Thank you! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understand your question correctly. This is my solution.
If you query for "Game5" you will get whole object that contains query

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Action",
    games: [
      { id: 1, title: "Game1" },
      { id: 2, title: "Game2" },
      { id: 3, title: "Game3" },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Horror",
    games: [
      { id: 1, title: "Game4" },
      { id: 2, title: "Game5" },
      { id: 3, title: "Game6" },
    ],
  },
];

const query = "Game5";
const result = data.find((category) =>
  category.games.find((g) => g.title === query)
);

console.log(result);
```

You can use 'filter' instead of 'find' and result will be an array.
This is example of filter version. I add one more category so you can see how it filter

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Action",
    games: [
      { id: 1, title: "Game1" },
      { id: 2, title: "Game2" },
      { id: 3, title: "Game3" },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Horror",
    games: [
      { id: 1, title: "Game1" },
      { id: 2, title: "Game2" },
      { id: 3, title: "Game3" },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Comedy",
    games: [
      { id: 1, title: "Game5" },
      { id: 2, title: "Game6" },
      { id: 3, title: "Game7" },
    ],
  },
];

const query = "Game2";
const result = data.filter((category) =>
  category.games.find((g) => g.title === query)
);

console.log(result);
```

---

And you might want to look at life cycle `componentDidUpdate` if you write class component, but if you write function component you might want to use `useEffect`
This is [official react hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) explaination

---

**EDIT**: from your comment you might want something like this

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Action",
    games: [
      { id: 1, title: "Game1" },
      { id: 2, title: "Game2" },
      { id: 3, title: "Game3" },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Horror",
    games: [
      { id: 1, title: "Game1" },
      { id: 2, title: "Game2" },
      { id: 3, title: "Game3" },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Comedy",
    games: [
      { id: 1, title: "Game5" },
      { id: 2, title: "Game6" },
      { id: 3, title: "Game7" },
    ],
  },
];

const query = "Game5";
let result = null;
data.forEach((category) => {
  const game = category.games.filter((g) => g.title === query);
  if (game.length) result = { ...category, games: game };
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hello, is there any way to return only the searched object?

Ex:

    id: 3,
    title: "Comedy",
    games: [
      { id: 1, title: "Game5" },
    ],

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: If this answer your question please mark this topic as answered. 